# Marshaling a pointer to an array of types (managed C# -> unmanaged C++)

Tags: c#, pointers, double, unmanaged

I am having some trouble settling on a way to represent a structure that contains a pointer to an array of shorts in my managed code.  The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    short size;
    unsigned short** shortValues;
} UnmanagedStruct;
```

memory for '`shortValues`' is allocated inside unmanaged code -- therefore even though that field is simply a pointer to an array of short values, an additional level of indirection was added so that allocated memory is seen by the caller (managed code) too.  The '`size`' field represents the number of elements in the array.  How do I represent this in managed code?

I thought I'd pass it in just an `IntPtr`, then I couldn't figure out how to access the values once the unmanaged call returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is unsafe code ok?

```
public unsafe struct UnmanagedStruct
{
    public short size;
    public ushort** shortValues;
}

[DllImport("example.dll")]
public static extern void GetUnmanagedStruct(out UnmanagedStruct s);
```

If you have a pointer to an array of `ushort`s:

```
public static unsafe void WriteValues()
{
    UnmanagedStruct s;
    GetUnmanagedStruct(out s);
    for (var i = 0; i < s.size; i++)
    {
        ushort x = (*s.shortValues)[i];
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

If you have an array of null-terminated arrays of `ushort`s:

```
public static unsafe void WriteValues()
{
    UnmanagedStruct s;
    GetUnmanagedStruct(out s);
    for (var i = 0; i < s.size; i++)
    {
        for (ushort* p = s.shortValues[i]; p != null; p++)
        {
            ushort x = *p;
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code looks exactly right to me.  Thanks dtb!  While I have your attention, can I ask one other question?  I have posted it in another thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323797/marshaling-pointer-to-an-array-of-strings

Comment: BTW: it's better to update your question than to post an answer to your question with new details. Also, if an answer solves a your problem, don't forget to accept it! :)